# Why do I get an empty data response?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've gotten the built in read action to work in the past but now it is not working. I also created a custom action which will not work.

When I try to post the action to this url:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/teamtutorials:complete?access_token=AAACOYImsskcBAGlF33o6awIqxmQ078BVdHUY72CF7GUqTHUhEcpKLdH8ZCKeyQbBqBDlnHwUMwt5aLOzpBmiWQqpvWsNAeHDMPSo2OQZDZD&tutorial=http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/why-zen-coding-is-an-awesome-time-saver?

all I get in response is:

```
{
   "data": [

   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/teamtutorials:complete?access_token=AAACOYImsskcBAGlF33o6awIqxmQ078BVdHUY72CF7GUqTHUhEcpKLdH8ZCKeyQbBqBDlnHwUMwt5aLOzpBmiWQqpvWsNAeHDMPSo2OQZDZD&tutorial=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fteamtutorials.com\u00252Fweb-development-tutorials\u00252Fwhy-zen-coding-is-an-awesome-time-saver\u00253F&offset=25&limit=25"
   }
}
```

What causes this type of response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like the response you'd get to a HTTP GET request; you need to make a HTTP POST request to create a new action

if your code/proxy can't make POST request outbound or you can fake it by making a GET request and including an extra parameter `&method=post`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code is doing a POST request and getting no response. I loaded the url directly in the browser which is probably why you are seeing it as GET behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the tip though. Add that method=post param provides better feedback. It actually works if I run it in my browser as a post request. I'm not sure what is happening on my site. https://graph.facebook.com/me/teamtutorials:complete?access_token=AAACOYImsskcBAGlF33o6awIqxmQ078BVdHUY72CF7GUqTHUhEcpKLdH8ZCKeyQbBqBDlnHwUMwt5aLOzpBmiWQqpvWsNAeHDMPSo2OQZDZD&tutorial=http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/why-zen-coding-is-an-awesome-time-saver&method=post

Comment: Also, I am never seeing a post request in firebug when I run this function. I'm not sure why the FB javascript API is not allowing me to post.

Comment: You have to specify that it's a POST request in the call to FB.api(), e.g. `FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: 'Hello, World!' } );`

Comment: You should receive back an error, or the action ID for the new action posted, in your case